# How to use react-error-boundary package with a component that is wrapped with forwardRef()

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref, react-error-boundary

I have a component that is defined as

```
export const MapWithoutErrorBoundary = React.forwardRef<
  mapboxgl.Map | null,
  MapWithoutErrorBoundaryProps
>(
  (
    {
     .
     .
     .
```

but I want to also wrap it with the `ErrorBoundary` component, so that the ref forwarding still works and I want to add another prop that the wrapped component doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. We were using a `withErrorBoundary` HOC similar to [the one in the `react-error-boundary` package](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary/blob/a0a370c7fe145e5cf169063eb4b7ff1a059fd84c/src/index.tsx#L142-L159).

This does not forward a ref, so attempting to bind to the `ref` of a component that's wrapped `withErrorBoundary` fails with

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

I ended up wrapping the `withErrorBoundary` hook with `React.forwardRef` as well:

```jsx
export const withErrorBoundary = (Component, errorBoundaryProps) => {
  const Wrapped = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary {...errorBoundaryProps}>
        <Component {...props} ref={ref} />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );
  });
  
  const name = Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Unknown';
  Wrapped.displayName = `withErrorBoundary(${name})`;

  return Wrapped;
};
```

Note that if you are using TypeScript, the type of `ref` won't be correct. For example, if `Component` has a `ref` pointing to a `HTMLDivElement`, you would expect the `ref` forwarded by `withErrorBoundary` to also point to a `HTMLDivElement`.

I ended up using this typing to address that, which ended up being rather verbose:

```js
/**
 * For a given component props object of type `P`, if `P` includes a React ref,
 * return the ref's instance type (e.g. `HTMLDivElement`). Otherwise, return `never`.
 *
 * Similar to `React.ElementRef<C>`, but note that `React.ElementRef` accepts the type
 * of a *component* as its type argument, rather than the type of its props.
 */
type RefInstance<P> = 'ref' extends keyof P
    ? P['ref'] extends React.Ref<infer InstanceType>
        ? InstanceType
        : never
    : never;

// the comma in <P,> is required; otherwise it gets interpreted as JSX,
// rather than as a type parameter
export const withErrorBoundary = <P,>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
    errorBoundaryProps?: Props
): React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    React.PropsWithoutRef<P> & React.RefAttributes<RefInstance<P>>
> => {
    const Wrapped = React.forwardRef<RefInstance<P>, P>((props, ref) => {
        return (
            <GenericErrorBoundary {...errorBoundaryProps}>
                <Component {...props} ref={ref} />
            </GenericErrorBoundary>
        );
    });

    const name = Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Unknown';
    Wrapped.displayName = `withErrorBoundary(${name})`;

    return Wrapped;
};
```

Hope that helps!